# Npm badplatform

Tags: npm, npm-install

```html
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path path\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe path\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\work\\bw\\bwg-main\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (path\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (path\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (path\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at path\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at path\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at path\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (path\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (path\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (path\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at path\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at path\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at path\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python310\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\work\\bw\\bwg-main\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd path\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

`C:\Users\User>npm install -g n npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@9.1.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32"}) npm ERR! notsup Valid os:  !win32 npm ERR! notsup Actual os: win32`

I wanted to run my old project, but there were problems with nodesass and python 2.7. I dont rememeber exaclty what i did, but now i cannot even install anything without force flag. There was something about running terminal as admin and turning on and off smth. I couldnt find regarding this problem. Maybe there is a way resetting to previous npm

Comment: Hey I guess you're downloading `n` ? Why? 
what is `n`? I'm pretty sure you wanted to install something else and not `n`. Why don't you share a bit more ? maybe a screenshot?

Comment: n because i wanted to change version of npm.  I need to run old project of mine its on vue 2

Comment: The error message says you are missing Python2. Do you have that installed?

Comment: from the docs of n

`n does not work in native shells on Microsoft Windows (like PowerShell), or Git for Windows BASH, or with the Cygwin DLL.`

Why don't you try nvm to change the node version, it supports Windows.